# How to access a (REST) list of resources over network (from micro-services) ?

Tags: rest, networking, microservices, grpc, distributed-transactions

We are writing a REST API, to access a list of resources. The API controller in turn requests data from a microservice. Now, we have two options -

1. Creating a microservice function to return a single resource in one
   go. Calling this function in loop, asynchronously, to get all the
   resources.
2. Creating a single microservice function to return the list of resources.

Which option is preferable?
Please help listing the pros and cons, in terms of,

- load distribution
- API response time
- Network failures

Comment: By `Creating a single microservice function to return the list of resources` you mean `Creating another microservice to return the list of resources`, so you would have 2 different microservices?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu No. It would be a aggregation function in the same microservice. e.g. GET api/products/123/ and GET api/products/all/